# I'm getting an error when I try to inherit NSView?

Tags: class, cocoa, swift

There isn't much to explain here.  I'm trying to make my CustomView class inherit NSView, but I'm getting an error.

Error:

`use of undeclared type 'NSView' class CustomView: NSView {`

Code:

```
import Cocoa

class CustomView: NSView {

}
```

I've never used Cocoa before, so I'm probably just doing something stupid.  How can I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you are trying to work on a macos app, but you have created an iOS project in Xcode.

Try changing `NSView` into `UIView`: if it compiles, it means you have created an iOS project.

Comment: I'm positive it's an OS X project.  I changed to UIView and it still didn't work.

Comment: if it's a new project, have you tried creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, I tried creating a new one too.  NSRect seems to work, but it keeps saying NSView is undeclared.

Comment: Trying to figure out, as I haven't ever worked with macos apps (ios only): any change if you `import AppKit`?